# Webview in android studio with php?

Tags: java, php, android

I developed a website and opened an android application through android studio and used a webview to open the website within the application.

So far, everything works fine, but I have a file type input, the site works normally, accessing it via a browser, but in the app it doesn't open the image gallery, how can I make it work?